# php file else condition output is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

Login.php

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST["insert"])) 
{ 
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pwd = $_GET['pass'];

//$sql =sqlsrv_query($conn,"select RegNo,UserName,password from Std_Reg where Username= '$user' and Password = '$pwd'");

$sql = "select RegNo,UserName,password from Std_Reg where Username= '$user' and Password = '$pwd'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

 if (!empty($stmt)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (count($stmt) > 0) {

            $stmt = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            $product = array();
            $product["RegNo"] = $stmt["RegNo"];
            $product["UserName"] = $stmt["UserName"];
            $product["password"] = $stmt["password"];

            // success
            $result["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $result["product"] = array();


            array_push($result["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($result);


        } else {
            // no product found
            $result["success"] = 0;
            $result["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($result);

        }

        //sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnection first  

    }


}
?>
```

I have connected to MS SQL Server to PHP File.if condition work properly but else part is not work.I have wrong parameter passed its give output

```
{"success":1,"product":[{"RegNo":null,"UserName":null,"password":null}]}.
```

but right else part output is

```
{
    "success": 0,
    "message": "No product found"
}
```

Comment: `have wrong parameter passed`=> what wrong parameter passed? share with us

Comment: in database stored username and password passed give output is correct but username and password wrong passed give out  {"success":1,"product":[{"RegNo":null,"UserName":null,"password":null}]}. instaed of { "success": 0, "message": "No product found" }.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

`$stmt` is either `FALSE` (when there is a connectivity issue, a syntax error in the query or it refers an object that doesn't exist) or a PHP resource.

Because `$stmt` is neither an array nor an object that implements the [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface, `count($stmt)` always returns `1`.

Use [`sqlsrv_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) to get the number of rows returned by the query or (if you don't care about the number) use [`sqlsrv_has_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-has-rows.php):

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($stmt) {
    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $product = array(
            'RegNo' => $row['RegNo'],
            'UserName' => $row['UserName'],
            'password' => $row['password'],
        );
        $result = array(
            'success' => 1,
            'product' => array($product),
        );
    } else {
        // no product found
        $result = array(
            'success' => 0,
            'message' => 'No product found',
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```